# CSS: Hover one element, and create two boxes?

Tags: html, css, hover, sequence

I am learning HTML/CSS for school.
I wanted to create a bar menu that if someone hover one button shows the blue bar (see snippet) **and** it creates below a Box for a Dropdownmenu. The Problem I get it only to work for one object the second one gets ignored even if I put my second object into  so that both balken and Dconfig are directly under the button-class.

I really dont know how to solve it and it.
I hope you can help me :)

```css
header {    
    background-color: black;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;  
}   

/*ButtonsCSS*/

.button{   
    height: 73px;
    top: -2px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border-color: transparent;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
   
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
}

.balken{
    opacity: 1; 
}

.button:hover + .balken{
    background-color:  rgba(108, 155, 243, 0.945);
    height: 4px;
 
    position: absolute;
    top: 66px;
}


.UeberCG{   
    left: 470px;
    border-right-width: 17px;
}
.balkenUeberCG{
    width: 80px;
    /**/
    left: 475px;
}

/*DropdownCSS*/


.Dconfig{
    opacity: 1;
}
.button:hover + .Dconfig{
    background-color: rgb(223, 217, 217);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
   
    position: absolute;
    top:70px;
}

.DUeberCG{
left: 470px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">


<body>
  <header>      

    <div class="Buttons">          
      <button class="button UeberCG">Über CG</button>
      <div class="balken balkenUeberCG"></div>
    </div>    

    <div class="Dropdownmenue">
        <div class="Dconfig DUeberCG"></div>  
        <div class="Suchleiste"></div>         
    </div>

      </header> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope so I understanded your requirements well. On button hover you want to show Dropdownmenu? If that is the case you have to wrap everything into one parent div, applying hover on that div will trigger actions on children divs (this is the only possible way with pure CSS while in Javascript it is different and html elements can be in different places).

Here is an example of how I figured out your requirements.

```css
.Buttons {
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: black;
}

.button-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: white;
  background: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.balken {
  background-color: rgba(108, 155, 243, 0.945);
  height: 4px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.button-wrapper:hover .balken {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.Dropdownmenu {
  background-color: rgb(223, 217, 217);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.button-wrapper:hover .Dropdownmenu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Buttons">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <button class="button UeberCG">Über CG</button>
    <div class="balken balkenUeberCG"></div>

    <div class="Dropdownmenu">
      <div class="Dconfig DUeberCG"></div>
      <div class="Suchleiste"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope so this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you man! Exactly what I was searching for

Comment: No problem, just mark it as accepted answer so others searching the same can find it usefull. Cheers.